# Incrementation Array element by value from label input

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, push, increment

I have a code in JavaScript where I want increment value of items by adding label input from the user. I created an input label and button to push values. I have an array of five items with unique Id's. The problem is when I add value from user input function can't push and concat existing values instead of creating a new part of the array.

```
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
          
          let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));   // Parse data from localstorage
          
          let elementimageUrl = element.imageUrl;                     // element.imageUrl is a part of backend data received from JSON file
          let elementId = element._id;                                // element._id is a part of backend data received from JSON file
          let elementName = element.name;                             // element.name is a part of backend data received from JSON file
          let elementPrice = element.price;                          // element.price is a part of backend data received from JSON file
          let add2 = document.getElementById("userinput").value;     // add2 variable get value from label
          let yInt = Number.parseInt(add2);                         // parse label value to Integer number
          console.log(yInt);                                        // console log to check number
          let elementQuantity = yInt;                               // assign label value to elementQuantity
          console.log(elementQuantity);

          if (!basket) {
            basket = [];
          }
        
          // find the index of the item if already in basket
          const itemIndexInBasket = basket.findIndex(basketEntry => basketEntry.elementId === elementId);
          if (itemIndexInBasket !== -1) {
            basket[itemIndexInBasket].elementQuantity++;
          } else {
            basket.push({elementId, elementName, elementPrice, elementQuantity, elementimageUrl});    // Push not existing data to localstorage
          } 
          localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(basket));
        })
```

This is how the button is able to push all values to an array. I expect increasing existing elementQuantity value instead of new element of an array.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal, yet working version of your full code, so we can debug it.

Comment: Please can you have look my GitHub? Code you can find in basket.js file. https://github.com/adrian9211/Project_5_eCommerce_Website/tree/master/frontend

Answer (score 0):

- Your code

```js
// find the index of the item if already in basket
const itemIndexInBasket = basket.findIndex(basketEntry => basketEntry.elementId === elementId);
if (itemIndexInBasket !== -1) {
  basket[itemIndexInBasket].elementQuantity++;
} else {
  basket.push({elementId, elementName, elementPrice, elementQuantity, elementimageUrl});    // Push not existing data to localstorage
}
```

### Reason of inconsistency

**Your `elementId` while you are comparing, it is `undefined` in `basketEntry.elementId === elementId`**

### What I have tried to see the value...

- Edit in your code

[image]

- Output

[image]

### Explanation

- That's why even if the product already exists it is appending a new  value to the last another value(only `elementQuantity` because other values are `undefined`).